# Run time TypeError: input.toLowerCase is not a function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, runtime, typeerror

While running my `react app`  I got the error : `TypeError: input.toLowerCase is not a function`.

Context: It's a form and I have a textfield inside a controller. Initially the field  id  which I'm working on was `string` but I needed to change it to `number`. That's when the type problems started.

I think the error comes from this line of my code :

```
                      inputValue={inputValue as unknown as string}

  onInputChange={(_e, newInputValue) => {
                        setInputValue(parseInt(newInputValue)); //this line
                      }}
```

using `parseInt` was the way that I found to get rid of this initial error :

```
Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<number>'.ts
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your code is doing, but it seems that somewhere, probably in `setInputValue`, the code is executing `input.toLowerCase`. Since you parsed the `string` to a `number`, `input.toLowerCase` will fail.